# LOAD DATA INFILE doesn't load all my data

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I have 1048 rows of csv data I need to read in. The data looks like this:

```
\N,Olenevka,Оленевка,2596
\N,Urzuf,Урзуф,2904
\N,Lebedyn,ЛЕБЕДИН,27695
\N,Staryy Dobrotvor,Staryy Dobrotvor,6436
```

Here is the table:

```
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| city_id    | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| alt_name   | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| population | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Here is the code:

```
db.query(""" 
    LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' 
    INTO TABLE %s 
    CHARACTER SET utf8
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    (@skip, name, alt_name, population) 
    """ % (temp_file, table))

class Database(object):
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
    def query(self, cmd):
        return subprocess.call(['mysql -u root -e "%s" %s' % (cmd, self.database)], shell=True)
```

When I issue the command from python, it only reads in 1025 rows. But if I issue the same command from a mysql prompt, I get them all.

Here is the last rows from a SELECT * after running the code:

```
|    1023 | Alchevs’k        | Алчевск                             |     116000 |
|    1024 | Yakymivka        | Якимівка                            |      12353 |
|    1025 | Okhtyrka         | Охтирка                             |      49818 |
|    1026 | Adzhamka         | А                                   |          0 |
+---------+------------------+-------------------------------------+------------+
```

The last line is only partly read. Here is the rest of the file.

```
\N,Okhtyrka,Охтирка,49818
\N,Adzhamka,Аджамка,3859
\N,Malynivka,Малинівка,7502
\N,Mykhaylivka,Mykhaylivka,3352
\N,Kopashnovo,Копашново,3010
\N,Narkevychi,Наркевичі,1631
\N,Kirove,Кірове,3291
\N,Orikhove,Оріхове,3000
\N,Krasni Okny,Красні Окни,5461
\N,Pavlivka,Pavlovka,738
\N,Kuchurhan,Кучурган,3183
\N,Smyga,Смыга,2800
\N,Tayirove,Таїрове,1849
\N,Teplodar,Теплодар,8502
\N,Komsomolsk,Комсомольськ,51740
\N,Славутич,Славутич,25000
\N,Розгирче,Розгирче,566
\N,Orzhiv,Оржів,4125
\N,Shkil’ne,Шкільне,2127
\N,Denyshi,Деныши,1164
\N,Chetfalva,Четфалва,755
\N,Stepove,Степовое,1549
\N,Scholkine,,11677
\N,Yuzhnoukrains'k,Южноукраїнськ,39430
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a backslash at the end of each line, like this:

```
db.query("""\
    LOAD DATA INFILE '%s' \
    INTO TABLE %s \
    CHARACTER SET utf8 \
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' \
    (null, name, alt_name, population) \
    """ % (temp_file, table))
```

If that doesn't work, try disabling shell processing from the "subprocess.call" call.

Eg:

> shell=False